# MariaDB Dependencies issue after isntall/remove

Tags: debian, mysql, dependencies, mariadb, phpmyadmin

I tried to "upgrade" MySQL 5.5 to MariaDB by removing MySQL altogether. Then I installed MariaDB 10.1 as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/debian jessie main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
service apache2 restart
```

But afterwards, phpMyAdmin did not load, and was returning 404. The app I was using was loading fine, and I was able to connect to the Database via command line. and `mysql -V` returned mariadb version.

So I removed phpMyAdmin, and MariaDB as follows:

```
service mysql stop
apt-get --purge remove "mysql*"
mv /etc/mysql/ /tmp/mysql_configs/
apt-get remove --purge mysql*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
apt-get purge phpmyadmin
apt-get autoremove phpmyadmin
service apache2 restart
apt-get update
```

cleared the mariadb entries in the sources file: `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Now, each time I try to `apt-get install` anything it returns me an error:

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server-10.0 : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (>= 10.0.22-0+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: mariadb-server-core-10.0 (>= 10.0.22-0+deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
                       PreDepends: mariadb-common but it is not going to be installed
                       Breaks: mysql-server
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-client-5.5
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This erros is for anything I try to install. And I did try to `apt-get -f install`. Any ideas what I messed up and how to fix it?

Notes:

```
lsb_release -da
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
Release:        8.2
Codename:       jessie

apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Aug 28 2015 16:28:08
```

Comment: I am not seeing there anything to remove mariadb. If your step list is complete, you forgot to remove it. Add back the repository and run apt-get -f install